# Xpath to find the element with the maximum value for a given child

Tags: java, xpath

Here is the XML:

```
<root>
  <ACTS>
    <ACT>Play</ACT>
    <A>
      <Day>1</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:42 IST 2014</time>
    </A>
    <A>
      <Day>2</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A>    
  </ACTS>
  <ACTS>
    <ACT>Study</ACT>
    <A>
      <Day>1</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:42 IST 2014</time>
    </A>
    <A>
      <Day>2</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A> 
    <A>
      <Day>3</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A>   
  </ACTS>
</root>
```

How can I find the element `A` and its children for `ACT` = `'Study'` for which the value of `Day` is maximum? Here is the Java program:

```
String xp = "//ACTS[ACT='Study']/A[not(Day < //ACTS[ACT='Study']/A/Day)]";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xp);
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
if (null != nl && null != nl.item(0)) {
    String abc = nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
    System.out.println(abc);
}
```

Note: With this XPath I am able to get the maximum value for `Day` by

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
if (null != nl && null != nl.item(0)) {
    maxAttemptNumber = nl.item(0).getTextContent();
}
```

but need help in getting element A and its children.

Comment: XPath is case sensitive. You use `Act`, but your XML seems to have `ACT`. Change this and your expression will work.

Comment: @Tomalak accepted... the xml given here is a dummy xml which looks similar to the actual one. so only those case sensitivity isuues...   
Editted the code...   
here i nedd to know how to get the details from nodelist

Comment: I have fixed your question format but I have no idea what you're asking. If you find the correct `<A>` (and your code seems to do that), then its children are attached to it.

Comment: This simple xpath 2.0 is able to get your desired A element : //ACTS[ACT='Study']/A[Day = max(for $x in //ACTS[ACT='Study']/A return $x/Day)]

Comment: When asking XPath questions, please specify XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0. The answers are likely to be very different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, then you can use XQuery as easily as XPath 2.0 or XPath 1.0 (e.g. with the Saxon library). The answer is then

```
(for $a in //ACTS[ACT="Study"]/A
order by number($a/Day))[last()]
```

Comment: In the code i have added in the question.. it is given as `NodeList nl`    How can i get childnodes and values from `nl`

Comment: I've suggested you use XQuery rather than XPath, if you go down that route then you'll be using a different API so your NodeList code will no longer be relevant.